# Custom Python Exceptions: Different name but same task

Tags: python, exception

I've a requirement to show custom messages sometime and at other times to show the exception message thrown by the application. So, I'm planning to implement something similar but I am not sure how to do that.

```
class A(Exception):
    """Base class for exceptions in this module."""
    pass


class B(A):
    """Expect a custom message here."""
    def __init__(self, err_msg):
        super(B, self).__init__(err_msg)
        self.err_msg = err_msg

    def __str__(self):
        return self.err_msg


class C(A):
    """Expect a custom message here."""
    def __init__(self, err_msg):
        super(C, self).__init__(err_msg)
        self.err_msg = err_msg

    def __str__(self):
        return self.err_msg


class D(A):
    """Expect the default behavior here."""
    pass
```

I was wondering is if I can eliminate repeating the **init** and **str** parts and merge them in A itself?

Comment: There is absolutely no need to implement `__str__` at all. `Exception` already provide a way to pass a custom message: `>>> raise Exception("custom message")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: custom message`
I hope you aren't subclassing `A` for the *only* sake of providing a custom message, in which case I'd simply remove the subclasses and use `A` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyException(Exception):
    """Expect a custom message here."""
    def __init__(self, err_msg):
        super(MyException, self).__init__(err_msg)
        self.err_msg = err_msg

    def __str__(self):
        return self.err_msg


def CustomExceptionA(MyException):
    pass

def CustomExceptionB(MyException):
    pass
```